# Función Node.js para agrupar (como group by) un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hice una función que agrupa los valores `time` en un arreglo conforme al `id`.

> ```
> [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}]
> ```

El resultado esperado es:

> ```
> {"a": [1,2], "b": [1]}
> ```

Este es mi código:

```
const obj = [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}];

const objMapped = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let { id, time } = item;
  acc[id] = acc[id] || [];
  acc[id].push(time);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(objMapped);
```

Se trata de volver un array en Map.

Comment: Yo he ejecutado tu código (sin modificaciones) y en ambos casos devuelven una estructura igual ¿podrías apoyar a detallar cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál el erróneo? indúcenos en como replicarlo para lograr apoyarte. Funcionaría que pongas: ¿qué hace?, ¿qué espero?, ¿qué devuelve?, ¿cómo replicarlo?.

Comment: Se solicitaron detalles para aclarar esta pregunta y estos nunca se agregaron.

Answer (score 1):

Para agrupar, deberías agregar cada valor al acumulado de `acc[item.id]`.

```js
const obj = [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}];

const objMapped = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  (acc[item.id] = acc[item.id] || []).push(item.time);
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(objMapped);
```